# I am getting "404 - File or Directory Not Found" Any ideas how to resolve this?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to use this JavaScript below to attempt to open a file when invoked.

```
function openFile() {
    document.getElementById("advanceSearchFrame").src = location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Profiles/Options.php";
    dijit.byId("advanceSearchDialog").show();

}
```

This JS is in a folder call Scripts.

This scripts folder is inside a folder called Profiles.

The file that I am trying to open called Options.php is also inside the Profiles folder.

When I click the Options folder, I get "404 -  File or Directory Not Found"

What do I need to change to fix the code above?

Comment: Well.. a 404 means that your server can't find the page you're referring to. In other words, you should take a look at the `location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Profiles/Options.php";` output.

Comment: have you checked that both the paths have the same lower and uppercase characters?

Comment: Why are you trying to open a PHP file with JavaScript?

Comment: @JasonSwett I would have said it might be an ajax request.. but doesn't seem like it

Comment: Do you get 404 if you dump the url, and try to enter it from the browser?

Comment: i guess He is trying to load a php page to an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. My original syntax was right all along. The issue was either it didn't like the fact that Options started with upper case O or it simply didn't like the name. As soon as I changed the name to opts.php, it worked